# $\pi$ is irreducible iff $\langle\pi\rangle$ is a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a domain of principal ideals. Then prove that $\pi \in R$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $\langle\pi\rangle$ is a maximal ideal.
Now I don't remember if R has multiplicative identity in the hypothesis, but I think it must have it.
Also, here I use "ideal"$\equiv$"bilateral ideal". I've already proved the first part, so I have $\pi$ irreducible $\Rightarrow\ \langle\pi\rangle$ is maximal, but i have trouble with the second part.
So suppose $\langle\pi\rangle$ is maximal $\Rightarrow\ \langle\pi\rangle$ is prime, i.e.  $\forall\ a,b\in R$ such that $ab\in \pi R=R\pi=\langle\pi\rangle$ (since R is an IPD), then $a\in \pi R$ or $b\in \pi R$, this implies $\pi\mid a$ or $\pi\mid b\ $ i.e. $a=\pi\cdot r'$ or $\ b=\pi\cdot r''$ and $ab=\pi\cdot r$ for some $r,r',r''\in R$ but I don't see how this shows that $\pi$'s only divisors are $\pi$ itself and unities (here's why I say $R$ must have $1$, since all unities are asociated to $1$ [I'm using "$1$"$\equiv$"multiplicative identity"]).

Comment: If $a \mid \pi$ then $\langle \pi \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle$, therefore...

Comment: I also thought that but i wasn't so sure about it. So i supposed that $\pi\nmid b$ so that implies $mR\subseteq bR$? But, since $\pi R$ is maximal, then $bR=R$ so $b=1$?

Comment: A couple of notes: it is extremely rare to be talking about a PID without identity, and rare to talk about a noncommutative PID. As written several things you said are wrong for noncommutative PIDs. For example, there are examples with $\pi R\neq R\pi$ and $\pi R\neq \langle\pi\rangle$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I'm Mexican, so I usually don't know the english vocabulary for math, thanks for the correction though. I've already changed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

> Let $\pi=fg$ where $f,g\in R$, then $\left<\pi\right>\subseteq\dots$

Comment: Now I see this could have been a better proof. So I suppose $\pi$ is not irreducible, so $\pi=p\cdot q$ with $p,q \in R$, this implies $\pi R\subseteq pR$ or $\pi R\subseteq qR$ i.e. $p\mid \pi$ or $q\mid \pi$, but since $\pi R$ is maximal then $pR=\pi R$ or $pR=R$ i.e. $p=\pi$ or $p=1$ and analogously for $q$, so $\pi$ is rreducible?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote as if you were considering noncommutative PID's (you emphasized you were talking about bilateral ideals, and you used $\langle\cdot \rangle$) I offer these comments.

It happens that there exist [simple left-and-right PID's](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=65l&H=65r&H=3&L=2) which aren't division rings.  In such a ring, $\langle x\rangle$ is the entire ring for every nonzero element, even "irreducibles" (however you are defining them).

In such a ring, it is not necessarily true that any of $xR, Rx$ or $\langle x\rangle$ are equal, although the lattermost contains the first two, of course.

Along with being more careful about defining irreducibility in a noncommutative PID, you'd have to be careful defining divisibility as well. It is pretty rare to see the noncommutative version discussed, although I know several papers by P. M. Cohn apply.

For these reasons, I think you're better off confining yourself to the commutative version so that you can follow your line of thought to a successful conclusion.

Comment: Well, the definition I have of an IPD requires the ring to be an integral domain i.e. my ring $R$ must be commutative, that's why i supposed it since the beggining, but it's still interesting to know your non-commutative examples

Comment: But, by mere curiosity, how does the proof go if we take non-commutative IPD's?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas If you want to assume commutativity, that’s fine, but you were doing a great job pretending to be worried about one-sided ideals by emphasizing you meant bilateral ideals.  I’m not sure what is true in the noncommutative case. You’d have to settle on a definition of irreducibility and divisibility first.  Anyhow, I gave a counterexample to show that $\langle\pi\rangle=R$ can occur, disproving the statement for noncommutative PIDS in general.